# How to include labels from a supplementary column in MCA visualisation using MCA?

Tags: r, label, factorial, mca

I have this data frame

```
df <- data.frame(subjects = 12:23,
                 Why_are_you_not_happy = 
                   c(1,2,"1,2,5",5,1,2,"3,4",3,2,"1,5",3,4),
                 why_are_you_sad = 
                   c("1,2,3",1,2,3,"4,5,3",2,1,4,3,1,1,1))
df
```

that is coverted into this format

```
df1 <- df %>%
  separate(Why_are_you_not_happy,
           sep = ",", into = c("Why_are_you_not_happy_1",
                               "Why_are_you_not_happy_2",
                               "Why_are_you_not_happy_3")) %>%
  separate(why_are_you_sad,
           sep = ",", into = c("why_are_you_sad_1",
                               "why_are_you_sad_2",
                               "why_are_you_sad_3"))
```

when applying the MCA function we take all the columns except the first one

```
library(FactoMineR)
library(factoextra)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

results <- MCA(df1[,2:7])
```

However when looking at the graph of the individuals, they are labeled from 1 to 12, and what I wish is that the labels come from the *subjects* column. How can I make that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could set the row names to subjects column

```
library(FactoMiner)
MCA(`row.names<-`(df1[-1], df1$subjects))
```

Comment: Appreciate the help thanks